# Regex: Delete duplicate double quote (apostrophe) on a html tag (from string)

Tags: notepad++, regex, html

I have this html tag (from string):

`<meta name="description" content="I love my mother" but I love my sister" more than I can say"/>`

As you can see, I have 4 double quote (apostrophe) in the *content* section. Should be only 2 double quote: one at the beginning `content="` and one at the end `"/>`

I must find all tags that contains other double quote except those 2 in the content section, and delete them:

Output should be:

`<meta name="description" content="I love my mother but I love my sister more than I can say"/>`

I made a Regex, but not too good. Maybe you can help me:

FIND: `(?-s)(<meta name="description" content=")(*?\K.*"(?s))"/>`

REPLACE BY: `\1\2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<meta name="description" content="|\G(?!^))[^"]*\K"(?=.*?"/>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
  <meta name="description" content="      # literally
 |               # OR
  \G(?!^)         # restart from last match position (not at the beginning of a line)
)               # end group
[^"]*           # 0 or more non quote
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
"               # a double quote
(?=.*?"/>)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have "/>  somewhere after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qgUbps/1)

Comment: thanks again @Toto

Comment: @RobRob: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: can you please tell me what does this `(?:` non-capture group doing in your regex? This I do not understand very good.

Comment: @RobRob: `(?: ... )` acts as a group `( ... )` but doesn't capture the matched data. It's really much more efficient than a standard capture group. It is use when you want to group something but don't need to reuse it later. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html